# Comandos en gitbash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Estoy aprendiendo aún a trabajar con comandos git, he aprendido cosas básicas. Hace poco tuve un problema, subía cambios a un servidor local pero luego cambié a un servidor en linux, trabajando en un proyecto clonado de github, luego de volver a mi servidor local y volver a subir cambios y dejar el servidor linux, no se guardaban los cambios que realizaba y los que sí habían registrado no los podía subir, cuando trataba de hacer commit luego de añadir los ficheros, me mostraba errores tipo:

```
  nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Cuando en realidad había hecho muchos cambios, leí cosas en inglés sobre 'untracked working tree' y algo sobre que los archivos se poodían desenrutar, y que podría borrar la carpeta .git y volver a crear un repositorio y volver a subir los cambios, pero luego tenía esto:

```
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by 
checkout:
'mis archivos cambiados'
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Al final leyendo otra pregunta en esta página en inglés encontré esta solución:

```
 git clean  -d  -fx
```

Aunque me borró todos los archivos desenrutdos, solucionó lo de no poder subir cambios y tuve que volver a hacerlos.
La verdad no entiendo bien este tema, me gustaría saber a qué exactamente se refiere que el término 'untracked files' y por qué sucede esto y cómo puede solucionarse sin que se elimine todo y cómo evitar este tipo de error que da muchos dolores de cabeza.

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: Hacías commits y luego te daba ese error?

Comment: sí, me decía nothing to commit al inicio y luego de crear el nuevo repositorio  intentar nuevamente hacer commits, me salía lo segundo.

Comment: un `nothing to commit` no es un error, simplemente no tienes nada para "comitear", en primer lugar, tienes que establecer que archivos vas a seguir con `git`, esto con `git add <archivo>`

Comment: Al hacer git status sí me mostraba los cambios y lo que dices es lo que hacía con git add . para que agregue todos o lo hacía por archivos y pues al final seguía mostrando nothing to commit, yo sé que no es un error en sí pero en este contexto contribuía como error ya que sí habían muchos cambios y aún así seguía sin nada que hacer commit, y luego el siguiente error que comento.

Comment: Igual como digo, estoy aprendiendo aún, y otro error que olvidé en la pregunta, es cuando me decía "allow unrelated histories".